# Implying form the Symmetry of the sum of von Mangoldt function

Tags: prime-numbers, analytic-number-theory, symmetry, arithmetic-functions

In the article ["On the Selberg-Erdos Proof of The Prime Number Theorem" by Ashvin A. Swaminathan](https://scholar.princeton.edu/sites/default/files/ashvin/files/math229xfinalproject.pdf), page 5, it is written -

> By rearranging the claimed equality, it suffices to show that
> $$\sum_{\substack{mn≤x\\ m, n \; \text{not both prime}}} Λ(m)Λ(n) = O(x)$$
> and **BY SYMMETRY**, it further suffices to show that
> $$\sum_{\substack{mn≤x\\ m\; \text{not prime}}} Λ(m)Λ(n) = O(x)$$

QUESTION:

1. How the symmetry is working here? What is the meaning of symmetry here?
2. How **BY SYMMETRY**, it is  suffices to show that
   $\sum_{\substack{mn≤x\\ m\; \text{not prime}}} Λ(m)Λ(n) = O(x)$ from $\sum_{\substack{mn≤x\\ m, n \; \text{not both prime}}} Λ(m)Λ(n) = O(x)$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The two-parametric function
\begin{align*}
\Phi_{m,n}(x)&=\sum_{{mn\leq x}\atop{m\,\text{not prime}}}\Lambda(m)\Lambda(n)\\
\end{align*}
in $x$ is *symmetric* in the parameters $m$ and $n$
\begin{align*}
\Phi_{m,n}(x)=\Phi_{n,m}(x)
\end{align*}

---

If we can show the validity of
\begin{align*}
\color{blue}{\sum_{{mn\leq x}\atop{m\,\text{not prime}}}\Lambda(m)\Lambda(n)=\mathcal{O}(x)}\tag{1}
\end{align*}
we have by *symmetry* (i.e. exchanging $m$ with $n$)
\begin{align*}
\sum_{{nm\leq x}\atop{n\,\text{not prime}}}\Lambda(n)\Lambda(m)=\mathcal{O}(x)
\end{align*}
from which
\begin{align*}
\sum_{{mn\leq x}\atop{m\,\text{not prime}}}\Lambda(m)\Lambda(n)
+\sum_{{mn\leq x}\atop{n\,\text{not prime}}}\Lambda(m)\Lambda(n)
=\mathcal{O}(x)+\mathcal{O}(x)
=\mathcal{O}(x)\tag{2}
\end{align*}
follows.

> Since
> \begin{align*}
> \sum_{{mn\leq x}\atop{m,n\,\text{not both prime}}}\Lambda(m)\Lambda(n)
> &\leq \sum_{{mn\leq x}\atop{m\,\text{not prime}}}\Lambda(m)\Lambda(n)
> +\sum_{{mn\leq x}\atop{n\,\text{not prime}}}\Lambda(m)\Lambda(n)\tag{$\ast$}\\
> \end{align*}
> we have from (2)
> \begin{align*}
> \color{blue}{\sum_{{mn\leq x}\atop{m,n\,\text{not both prime}}}\Lambda(m)\Lambda(n)=\mathcal{O}(x)}\tag{3}
> \end{align*}
> **Conclusion:** The validity of (1) is sufficient *by symmetry* to show (3).

---

---

**Add-on:** With respect to OP's question in the comment section we look at the inequality ($\ast$) and analyse when a strict inequality $(<)$ is given.

Given a sum in the form $\sum_{n\leq x}f(n)$ where $f$ is an arithmetical function, we consider $x$ to be a *positive real number*. So the sum is defined to be
\begin{align*}
\sum_{n\leq x}f(n):=\sum_{n=1}^{\lfloor x\rfloor}f(n)
\end{align*}
with $\lfloor x \rfloor$ being  the *[integral part](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floor_and_ceiling_functions)* of $x$. Taking $x$ as a positive real number is convenient since then we can use for instance the *[big-O](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation)* machinery for estimation. In case of $0<x<1$ the sum is the *empty sum* and set to $0$. See e.g. sections 3.1 and 3.2 in *[Introduction to  Analytic Number Theory](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0387901639)* by T.M. Apostol.

The *[Von Mangoldt function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Von_Mangoldt_function)* $\Lambda(n)$ takes non-negative values only, so that
\begin{align*}
\sum_{mn\leq x}\Lambda(m)\Lambda(n)\tag{$\ast\ast$}
\end{align*}
is monotonically increasing with $x$.

When going through small pairs $(m,n)$ with increasing sum $m+n\geq 1$ we have to find out the first occurrence where *both* values $m,n$ have a form $p^k$ with $p$ prime and $k>1$. Because this  is the first time where both sums of the RHS of ($\ast$) provide a non-negative contribution which is then twice the contribution of the LHS.

The first pair is $(m,n)=(4,4)$ and we conclude due to monotonicity of ($\ast\ast$) that equality is given for $\color{blue}{0<x<16}$ and strict inequality for $\color{blue}{x\geq 16}$.

Comment: Very good explanation, but stuck at a point: When does the equality hold in $\begin{align*}
\sum_{{mn\leq x}\atop{m,n\,\text{not both prime}}}\Lambda(m)\Lambda(n)
&\leq \sum_{{mn\leq x}\atop{m\,\text{not prime}}}\Lambda(m)\Lambda(n)
+\sum_{{mn\leq x}\atop{n\,\text{not prime}}}\Lambda(m)\Lambda(n)\\
\end{align*}$?   Certainly I can think of some examples, but mathematically how I show that?

Comment: @Andrew: I've added some information in my answer. Regards,

Comment: @Andrew: Many thanks for providing this additional bounty. This is very generous of you. :-)